# Flask show first paragraph of the post as an excerpt

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I should be able to excerpt from a post like this in a jinja template.

```
{{post['content']|markdown | truncate(489)}}
```

Is there a way to show the first paragraph of the post as an excerpt.

Posts are stored in mongodb as markdown files.

**Update :** The code snippet which @davidism points out makes exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: did you already see this  http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/19 ?

Comment: I use Flask-Markdown extension for this library. May be at first glance I should convert it to html `html = markdown.markdown(post[0]['content'])` and than pull the first paragraph using Beautiful Soup.

Comment: what's your goal, you need the first paragraph, even if it contains 2000 characters ? otherwise you can use truncate or slice the text before you render the template

Comment: Sure I try to show the first paragraph of a post on index or /posts page even if contains a lot of characters. Here is an  [example](http://www.erdem.tk/arduino)   but it was coded with D.